# DataLoadOptions not loading linked table

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass data from my main table(Users) and a linked table(Posts) into a view, however, when I'm in the view I can't access any of the linked table data. I am using a model created using linq 2 sql, and i'm using the LoadWith method to include the data from the related table.

Here is the code in the ActionResult:

```
BlogModelDataContext context = new BlogModelDataContext();

DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<UserModel>(c => c.PostModels);
context.LoadOptions = dlo;

var users = from u in context.UserModels
                         where u.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
                         select u;

return View(users);
```

Here is the code in the ActionResults view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcBlog.Models.UserModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NewProfile";
 }

 <h2>NewProfile</h2>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
     @item.JoinDate
     @item.Username

     @foreach (var post in item.PostModels)
     {
         @post.
     }
 }
```

However, when I try to access the fields of the post table, nothing is displayed, and I get the following warning:

> Error 2   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' because
>   'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' does not
>   contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I thought once I use `LoadWith` I should be able to access the properties of the Post table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when using Linq and especially IEnumerable. Your current select statement returns an IEnumerable object. This means that the linq statement is not actually executed until you start iterating over the IEnumerable object (i.e. in your View). By adding a .ToList() will actually force that enumeration to be evaluated at that point.

You will then be passing a List of UserModels, with their PostModels, to your View.

In summary, add .ToList() to your linq statement.

```
var users = (from u in context.UserModels
             where u.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
             select u).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi David, I've added ToList() like you said, however, i'm not able to access the properties from the PostModels table.

Comment: Make sure there is definitely a reference in Linq between UserModels and PostModels. Open up the dbml file and double check the reference. Try removing from the dbml and re-adding.

Comment: Hi David, I checked the dmbl and there is a relationship between UserModel and PostModel. I've deleted the dbml and created a new one just in case, and i'm still having the issue.

Is this model declaration correct?

    @model IEnumerable<MvcBlog.Models.UserModel>

Comment: Yes, that is not the problem. Put a breakpoint on the 'var users...' and debug, at that point, why the PostModels are not loaded.